# using different files for a function, but I/O error because of using with

Tags: python, function

Im pretty new at this, so the answer to this problem might be rather easy. I'm just not seeing it atm. 
I have a function that is used to count the number of words that appear in a file. Within the function i use with file as fin, as shown below. If i try to re-use the function it gives the error that the file is closed. I solved it, but it looks bad (IMO):

```
def lcount(keyword):
    with file_to_count as fin:
        return sum([1 for line in fin if keyword in line])  


file_to_count = open('peer.txt', 'r')

y = lcount('bars')
print y

file_to_count = open('peer2.txt, 'r')
w = lcount('bar')

file_to_count = open('Peer2.txt', 'r')
e = lcount('table')

print w, e
```

If I do not restate

```
file_to_count = open('Peer2.txt', 'r')
```

for the second time(after i count 'bar'. it will give the I/O error while 'table' is going through the function.
So the code works, but I want to use lcount for other words, do I need to restate the file_to_count everytime or are there solutions/alternatives?

Thanks for you attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is is that you're using the `with` statement which is a context manager. Which basically makes sure that the file is closed at the end of the block. So, your function closes the file, and then you need to open it again.

But also, using a global object isn't a great idea, as you can see, it can(will) introduce a lot of subtle bugs. Try to make function don't depend things other than their parameters.

Like;

```
def lcount(fname, keyword):
    with open(fname) as fin:
        # Use a generator expr. to avoid intermediate list
        return sum(1 for line in fin if keyword in line)
        # Or better, since True == 1
        return sum(keyword in line for line in fin)

    #file is closed now

fname = "peer2.txt"
words = "bars bar table".split()

# don't repeat yourself
for word in words:
    print lcount(fname, word)
```

Comment: Thank you for explainng it. With this implementation my code will be alot clearer and less buggy:)

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your function with an argument for the file name:

```
def lcount(filename, keyword):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        return sum([1 for line in fin if keyword in line])
```

and use it like this:

```
y = lcount('peer.txt','bar')
w = lcount('peer2.txt','bar')
```

Comment: Thx for the quick response. This is indeed teh way to go, thx for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Thats a strange way to handle file IO through context manager, its more intuitive and accepted to use.

```
def lcount(fname,  keyword):
    with open(fname) as fin:
        return sum(1 for line in fin if keyword in line)
```

Also `sum` accepts a generator, so it may not be required to generate a list before calling `sum`.

**Note**

If you are curious, why your approch fails, remember, context manager calls the `__exit__` method of the object generated after evaluating the expression, after the end of the block, which in case of file object, closes the file. So, its important to limit the scope of the expression creating the object within the `with` statement, so as not to reopen the file everytime you invoke the `with` block.

Comment: @ Abhijit. Thanks again!:) I thought it was a simple solution. Thx for showing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should restructure things entirely. The `with` statement is meant to provide a scope for an object, so that the object is cleanly closed at the end. I'm not sure `file_to_count` is available as a global within the `with` statement, but that's a bad practice anyway - better to pass the file into the function.

```
def lcount(keyword, fin):
    return sum([1 for line in fin if keyword in line])  


with open('peer.txt', 'r') as file_to_count:
    y = lcount('bars', file_to_count)
    print y

with open('peer2.txt', 'r') as file_to_count:
    w = lcount('bar', file_to_count)
    file_to_count.seek(0)  # start over at the beginning of the file
    e = lcount('table', file_to_count)
```

Comment: I like this version because lcount() can be used with any file-like object.